# I want to SELECT [job_id],[name],[enabled] and [run_status] column from both tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server `[msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory]` and `[msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory]`, in which one column `Job_id` is common in both. I want to `SELECT` `[job_id]`,`[name]`,`[enabled]` and `[run_status]` columns from both tables.

Comment: use `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Is only `Job_id` present in both, and the rest are only in one of them? If what you need is simply map each row from one table to a row from the other table based on this column, I'd say you are much better off learning some SQL basics first. Otherwise, you will be asking dozens of questions like this, which will be downvoted for the lack of research.

Comment: Hi Manish, welcome to StackOverflow. This page explains how a `JOIN` clause can be used https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry for the typo, the tables names was following [sysjobservers] and [sysjobs]. here i got my final query : SELECT a.[job_id],[name],[enabled]
 ,[last_run_outcome]
      ,[last_outcome_message]
      ,[last_run_date]
      ,[last_run_time]
      ,[last_run_duration]
     FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] a 
  Inner Join [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobservers] b
  On a.job_id = b.job_id
Thanks for everyone out there for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are fetching data from [sysjobs] and [sysjobservers] which is available in MSDB system database.

```
SELECT a.[job_id],[name],[enabled]
 ,[last_run_outcome]
      ,[last_outcome_message]
      ,[last_run_date]
      ,[last_run_time]
      ,[last_run_duration]
     FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] a 
     Inner Join [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobservers] b
     On a.job_id = b.job_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select      a.job_id, name, enabled, run_status 
From        [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory] a
Inner Join  [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory] b
  On a.job_id = b.job_id
```

Comment: Adding some explanation would make this answer more useful.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Jon for helping me out here.